# Умножение значения на 2

Tags: c#

Возникло желание сделать цикл в котором число будет умножатся на 2 и так множество раз.

Примерно так `2 > 4 > 8 > 16 > 32 > 64 > 128 > 256 > 512 > 1024` и в таком порядке.

Но недоумеваю как это можно реализовать. Вроде бы по моему коду переменная `a` имеет изначальное значение `1`, и должна умножатся на `2` и записываться в переменную `b`, а сама переменная `b` умножаться тоже на `2`, и так по циклу.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "code";
            for (int a = 1; a < 16; a++)
            {
                int b;
                b = a * 2;
                Console.Write(" " + b * 2);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Но выходит какая-то путаница и к числу просто прибавляется 4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как правильно умножать в цикле значение, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: почему нельзя сделать `a` от 1 до N и возводить 2 в степень `a`?

Comment: и ещё, "выходит какая-то путаница и к числу просто прибавляется 4". А что вы ожидаете, если `b=2*a` и вы выводите `b*2`, а то-есть вы выводите `a*4`

Comment: @KuzCode Ну если сделать `a = 2` и возводить `2` в степень `a` то выходит подобное https://i.imgur.com/llDwW2C.png

Comment: `a` изменяется в цикле с единичным шагом, выводим 2 в степени `а`:
2^1 = 2,
2^2 = 4,
2^3 = 8,
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int b = 1;
for (int a = 1; a < 16; a++)
{
  b = b * 2;
  Console.Write(" " + b);
}
```

---

```
for (int a = 1, b = 2; a < 16; a++, b *= 2)
{
  Console.Write(" " + b);
}
```

Comment: Все теперь понятно стало, я не прав был в своем решении, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int a = 1; a < 16; a++)
{
    int b = (int)Math.Pow(2, a);
    Console.Write(" " + b);
}
```

Comment: `int b = 1 << a;` :)

Comment: @aepot кстати да, с двойкой побитовый сдвиг можно применить)